# Homology of the circle given by algebra generated by a single element

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have seen people say that homology of the circle is just an algebra over the coefficient field $\Bbb{F}$ generated by one element $x$ of degree $-1$. I know that cohomology has a multiplication which may be brought down to homology using Poincare duality, the circle also has homology $\Bbb{F}$ in degrees $0,1$. I am not sure what the terminology element of degree $-1$ means. If anything the algebra should be $\Bbb{F}[x]/(x^2)$ where the element has degree $1$ not $-1$. Can someone clarify what this means?

Answer (score 1):

First, Poincaré duality has nothing to do with it. The homology of $S^1$ has an algebra structure because $S^1$ is a topological group: the multiplication map $S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1$ induces a product structure on homology (the "Pontryagin product").

As far as degrees: when dualizing a graded object, people make different choices: when dualizing something in degree $n$, some people put the dual in degree $n$, some put it in degree $-n$. (Or maybe less directly: some people grade both homology and cohomology positively, while some might suggest that one should be graded positively, one negatively.) Since homology and cohomology are dual, at least with coefficients in a field $F$, if they are graded opposite to each other, then the evaluation map $H^n(S^1) \otimes H_n(S^1) \to H_0(X) \cong F$ is a degree zero map.